# Loop over a layer to do a Monte Carlo from a neural net output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, montecarlo

I've recently had to tweak a neural network. Here's how it works:

- Given an image as input, several layer turns it into a mean matrix `mu` and a covariance matrix `sigma`.
- Then, a sample `z` is taken from the Gaussian distribution of parameters `mu`, `sigma`.
- Several layer turns this sample into an output
- this output is compared to a given image, which gives a cost

What I want to do is to keep `mu` and `sigma`, take *multiple* samples `z`, propagate them through the rest of the NN, and compare the *multiple* images I get to a given image.

Note that the step `z` -> image output calls other package, I'd like not having to dig into these...

What I did so far :

- At first, I thought I did not need to go through all this hassle : I take a `batch_size` of one, it is as if I'm doing a Monte Carlo by running the NN multiple times. But I actually *need* the neural net to try several image before updating the weights, and thus changing `mu` and `sigma`.
- I simply sampled multiple `z` then propagated them through the net. But I soon discovered that I was duplicating all the layers, making the code **terribly** slow, and above all preventing me from taking many samples to achieve the MC I'm aiming at.

Of course, I updated the loss and data input classes to take that into account.

Do you have any ideas ? Basically, I'd like an efficient way to make `z` -> `output` multiple time, in a cost-efficient manner. I've still a lot to learn from tensorflow and keras, so I'm a little bit lost on how to do that. As usual, please apologized if an answer already exists somewhere, I did my best to look for one by myself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my question was a bit stupid. So as not to duplicate layers, I created multiple slice layers, and then I simply propagated them through the net with previously declared layers. Here's my code :

```
# First declare layers
a = layer_A()
b = layer_B()
# And so on ...
# Generate samples
samples = generate_samples()([mu, sigma])
# for all the monte carlo samples, do : 
for i in range(mc_samples):
    cur_sample = Lambda(lambda x: K.slice(x, (0, 0, 0, 2*i), (-1, -1, -1, 2)), name="slice-%i" % i)(samples)
    cur_output = a(cur_sample)
    cur_output = b(cur_output)
    all_output.append(output)
output_of_net = keras.layers.concatenate(all_output)
return Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output_of_net)
```

Simply loop over the last dimension in the loss function, average, and you're done ! A glimpse at my loss :

```
loss = 0
for i in range(mc_samples):
    loss += f(y_true[..., i], y_pred[..., i])
return loss/mc_samples
```

Comment: Hi @gasperdb,
This is interesting stuff. Would you mind posting your keras network architecture including compilation stage so I can take a look at the network and loss you used - I'm guessing you used KL divergence somehow to generate mu and sigma (much like in a variational autoencoder) and then MSE to compare your output?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi @A555h55. In fact, I tried to tweak the code from https://github.com/voxelmorph/voxelmorph ; my contribution only add to this modified loss function, plus a modification on the generator :
`yield ([X, atlas_vol_bs], [np.stack([atlas_vol_bs] * mc_samples, axis=-2), zeros])`
The author isn't using a VAE, but it is indeed very close to that. You can look at their implementation of a KL loss. Let me know if that's not clear!